# how to initialize a class when collecting data from db in firestore flutter provider

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider

I am following one tutorial on Flutter Ecommerce using Firestore and flutter provider.

I wanted to retrieve all the data from firestore Db, but the problem is I don't know how to initialize the class I am going to use to retrieve data from Db firestore. Pls help. And if you have better approaches you can share your knowledge with me. this is the code below:

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shopping/db/product.dart';
import 'package:shopping/models/product.dart';

 class AppProvider with ChangeNotifier {
   List<Product>_fearturedProducts=[];
   ProductService _productService=new ProductService();

   AppProvider(){
     //please how to initialize class AppProvider here 
 }
   //getter
   List<Product> get featuredProducts=>_fearturedProducts;

   //method
   void _getFeaturedProducts()async{

    _fearturedProducts=await _productService.getFeaturedProducts();
    notifyListeners();
   }
 }
```

### code for ProductService class:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:shopping/models/product.dart';

class ProductService{
    Firestore _firestore=Firestore.instance;
  String collection="Products";

  Future<List<Product>>getFeaturedProducts(){

 _firestore.collection(collection).where('featured', isEqualTo:true).getDocuments()
 .then((snap){

  List<Product>featuredProducts=[];
   snap.documents.map((snapshot)=> featuredProducts.add(Product.fromSnapshot(snapshot)));
   return featuredProducts;
 }); 

}

}
```

Comment: Can I ask what do you want to achieve with this constructor? Why it cannot be no-argument constructor?

Comment: i want to call it using changenotifier in the main.dart

Comment: something like this "     ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: UserProvider.initialize()),
" i will also make use of multi provider incase i have another changenotifier

Comment: Do you want to call it inside this AppProvider class?

Comment: in main.dart but i do not know the arguments that i will supply for the constructor

Answer (score 1):

I think that there may be many solution depending how you want to use AppProvider class.

Maybe you can do it like:

```
AppProvider(){
    this._getFeaturedProducts();
  }
```

Than in your main class init the object like:

```
AppProvider _appProvider = new AppProvider();
```

During object creation the data should be taken from firestore and all listeners will be notified.

I hope it will help!